# Advantages of using race in sagas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, redux-saga

I have a pattern in my app regarding redux-saga, that for asynchro calls I have two functions - the first one is listening to some specified action and the second one is making the call to the api.

1. Listener function:

   ```
   function* userJoinListener() {
      while (true) {
         const { user } = yield take(UserJoinRequest);

         const promiseRace = yield race({
            res: call(userJoinFunction, user),
            err: take(UserJoinError),
         });

         if (promiseRace.res) {
           // code if success
         } else {
           // code if fail
         }
      }
   }
   ```
2. Api call executing function:

   ```
   function* userJoinFunction(user) {
      try {
         return yield call(userJoin, user);
      } catch (err) {
         yield put(userJoinFail);
      }
   }
   ```

**My question is**:  what is the advantage of using `race` here exactly? To be honest, I could just use that second function in the same place as `race` is and it would work as expected:

```
function* userJoinListener() {
   while (true) {
      const { user } = yield take(UserJoinRequest);

      try {
         // code if success
         return yield call(userJoin, user);
      } catch (err) {
         // code if fail
         yield put(userJoinFail);
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you :)

**Related question**: [Difference between Promise.race() and try/catch in redux-saga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818153/difference-between-promise-race-and-try-catch-in-redux-saga)

### **Update**:

#### Advantages:

- ability to cancel request

Comment: Why do you want to use `Promise.race()` here? Neither `call` nor `take` produce a promise you could race.

Comment: As of using `race` effect combinator.  `const promiseRace = yield race({
         res: call(userJoinFunction, user),
         err: take(UserJoinError),
      }); if(promiseRace)...`. It seems you are missusing the combinator.  `promiseRace` will be an object that is always truthy. You need to desctructure it and check which effect won the "race" `const {res, err} = yield race(); if(err) { ... }`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko `userJoin` function inside `call` is an asynchro call (promise)

Comment: And finally it the particular case `race` combinator looks like an overkill to me. `try-catch` is more readable and straight forward. But imagine you want to allow user to cancel pending `UserJoinRequest` by dispatching some `CancelUserJoinRequest` action. It this case `try-catch` wont help and you do need to race two independent effects.

Comment: "call is an asynchro call (promise)". But `call` effect doesn't actually call your function. It creates an effect (plain object) describing your intention to call the function. Also what is the second promise you want to race with to use `Promise.race` instead of `race` combinator?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko it's an axios post request

Comment: My argument is the same. "Neither `call` nor `take` produce a promise". How do you want to use `Promise.race` with them??? **Right now you don't have `Promise.race` in your code other then in title.** Write some a code that does use it then somebody could probably tell you if there is any "advantage" of using it.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko redux-saga's race idea is similar to Promise.race() thats why i called it this way

Comment: But they are completly different things :) So you question made no sense before the edit.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thank you for clarifying it.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed using `race` here is unnecessary complex.

If you are handling errors or cancellation inside the called saga (`userJoinFunction`) itself, then just use `try..catch`/`cancel` as that is more straightforward.

If on the other hand you need to cancel the saga when something happens from the outside (timeout, user action) then it makes sense to use the `race` effect.